# Is it possible to format text that is displayed as a 'new' html element by javascript in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not even sure that the question is correctly describing what I would like to do.
If I have a form which fades out and is then determined whether to display again via a cookie, can the confirmation message be styled specifically in css?

For instance, I would like to make the `<h2>Success</h2>` green. Can I do this within my css file? or even at all?

```
$(function() {
    var completed = $.cookie( 'completed' ),
        form = $('#contactform'),
        msg = $('#contactf');
    if( ( completed != undefined ) && ( completed == 'done' ) ) {
        form.hide();
        msg.html( '<h2>Success</h2>Thankyou for submitting <b>the form.</b> We will get back to you as soon as possible.' ); 
    }
```

Edit: More specifically, name this a class so I can refer to it in my CSS rather than formatting all heading on my page which may be h2 also.

Comment: Just like `h2 { color: green; }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just provide a CSS style for your element.

CSS

```
.green { color: green; }
```

jQuery

```
 msg.html( '<h2 class="green">Success</h2>Thankyou for submitting <b>the form.</b> We will get back to you as soon as possible.' );
```

Comment: yes but is there a way I can do this where h2 is only green once the new text courtesy of the js fading the old form occurs? To prevent a h2 heading before the function from being green?

Comment: Actually, just put a class on the `h2` as it is only displayed when successful.

Comment: That was it, I swear I tried that earlier..obviously messed it up somewhere though. But all good now.

Answer (score 0):

Or just add it in the code itself:

```
msg.html( '<h2 style="color:green">Success</h2>Thankyou for submitting <b>the form.</b> We will get back to you as soon as possible.' );
```

Comment: I think I will just end up doing this. This is the easiest. But is there a way I could refer to it in my css, just the msg.html h2 element and not whatever the previous text displayed was?

Comment: Add a class to the `h2` - `<h2 class="green">` and define that class in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

h2{color: green;}

use it if their is no h2 on page